# Which preposition is correct in this context?

Tags: preposition

This sentence appears in today's DW [Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten](https://www.dw.com/de/06052021-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-57444860):

> Im Jahr 2023 soll sie bereits **bei** einer bemannten Mondumrundung eingesetzt werden.

My question is, is **bei** correct here and would **für** be correct instead of bei? Also, where could I find a reference to this, specific question regarding which preposition is correct in this context?

Comment: Context: "Musk hofft, dass die neue Rakete eines Tages Menschen und Fracht auf den Mars befördern wird. Im Jahr 2023 soll sie bereits bei einer bemannten Mondumrundung eingesetzt werden."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many prepositions could be used here, e.g. *bei, für, zu, während, anlässlich, zwecks, …* etc. In every case, they are the head of an [***adverbiale Bestimmung***](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung). The preposition conveys whether the adverbial is *final* (purpose), *temporal* or *modal* (or even something else). So the 'correct' preposition depends on the intended **meaning**:

- '**on** a mission to orbit the moon' (circumstances/context):
  ***bei** einer bemannten Mondumrundung*
- '**for** a manned moon orbit, **to** orbit the moon' (purpose):
  ***für** eine* [sic!] *bemannte* [sic!] *Mondumrundung*<sup>1</sup>
  ***zu** einer bemannten Mondumrundung*
  ***zwecks** einer bemannten Mondumrundung*
  (<sup>1</sup>NB: *für* governs the accusative)
- '**during** a manned moon orbit' (temporal):
  ***während** einer bemannten Mondumrundung*
- '**on the occasion** of a manned moon orbit' (circumstances or causal):
  ***anlässlich** einer bemannten Mondumrundung*

Apparently, the writer of the news didn't want us to tell 'for' what the rocket should be used, but rather in which context (literally *on the orbit*, but that can be understood as *on the mission to orbit the moon*). *Bei einem Einsatz* ('on a mission') is quite idiomatic, so that may have influenced the use of the verb like *etw. bei etw. einsetzen* as well.

You can find references on the 'right' preposition for each meaning when you search for the different kinds of *adverbiale Bestimmungen* ('adverbials'), or you can look-up the prepositions you find and look at the examples. [*DWDS*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bei#d-1-1-2) describes one meaning of *bei* as:

> II. bezeichnet die Gleichzeitigkeit eines Zustandes, Vorganges mit einem anderen (sich an gleichen Ort vollziehenden) Zustand, Vorgang

which means:

> II. denominates the simultaneousness of a state, process with another state, proces (taking place on the same location)

So it refers to circumstances/context.